# mock testing http - angular2

Tags: javascript, angular, http, testing, mocking

I have read many questions here and a few tutorials and I still can't get this working, I've copied the tutorials word-for-word and still no luck so I have no idea what the issue is. I'm pretty new to this stuff. Here's my code:

```html
import { TestBed, inject, async } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { MockBackend } from '@angular/http/testing';
import {
  BaseRequestOptions,
  HttpModule,
  Http,
  Response,
  ResponseOptions
} from '@angular/http';

import { ItemsService } from './items.service';
import { MOCKITEMS } from './mock-items';

describe('ItemsService', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [HttpModule],
      providers: [ItemsService]
    });
  });

  it('should construct', inject([ItemsService], (service) => {
      expect(service).toBeDefined();
  }));
});

describe('ItemsService Mock', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      providers: [
        ItemsService,
        MockBackend,
        BaseRequestOptions,
        {
          provide: Http,
          useFactory: (backend, opts) => new Http(backend, opts),
          deps: [MockBackend, BaseRequestOptions]
        }
      ],
      imports: [HttpModule]
    });
  });

  it('should construct', inject([ItemsService, MockBackend], (service, mockBackend) => {
    expect(service).toBeDefined();
  }));

  describe('#getItems()', () => {
    it('should return <Array<Items>>', inject([ItemsService, MockBackend], (service, mockBackend) => {
      const mockReponse = {
        data: [
          { itemCharId: 1, itemName: 'milk' },
          { itemCharId: 2, itemName: 'eggs' },
          { itemCharId: 3, itemName: 'meat' }
        ]
      }

      mockBackend.connections.subscribe((connection) => {
        connection.mockRespond(new Response(new ResponseOptions({ body: JSON.stringify(mockReponse) })));
      });

      service.getItems().subscribe((items) => {
        expect(items.length).toBe(3);
        expect(items[0].itemName).toEqual('milk');
        expect(items[1].itemName).toEqual('eggs');
        expect(items[2].itemName).toEqual('meat');
      });
    }));
  });
});
```

The tests are failing with expected undefined to be 3, etc. So I'm assuming it's not actually getting my mockResonse obj as the response or something on those lines? Could just be something small too I guess.

Service code:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';

@Injectable()
export class ItemsService {

  constructor(private http: Http) { }

  getItems() {
    return this.http.get('/api/items');
  }
}
```

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: *Could just be something small too I guess* - I wouldn't call the absence of `service` code small. It's quite huge. Please, provide all relevant code. It's necessary to get an idea on what you're testing.

Comment: Added service code in main post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In [the tutorial that was likely was followed](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/http/testing/index/MockBackend-class.html), service method returns `response.json().data`:

```
  getHeroes(): Promise<String[]> {
    return this.http.get('myservices.de/api/heroes')
        .toPromise()
        .then(response => response.json().data)
        .catch(e => this.handleError(e));
  }
```

So the response is mocked as `{ data: [...] }`.

While in the example in the question it returns `this.http.get('/api/items')` and doesn't call `response.json()`.

These are the reason why there are no errors except failed assertions; `items` has to be equal to `mockReponse`.

It should be

```
  getItems() {
    return this.http.get('/api/items').map(res => res.json());
  }
```

and

```
  const mockReponse = [
      { itemCharId: 1, itemName: 'milk' },
      { itemCharId: 2, itemName: 'eggs' },
      { itemCharId: 3, itemName: 'meat' }
  ]
```

This can additionally be asserted with

```
expect(items).toEqual(mockResponse);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I tried that and it's still giving me the same failures. The actual service just returns an array like you listed above so that's how I would like to get this working.

Comment: I'm not sure what's the problem. You expect `items` to be array, and you need `mockResponse` to be an array too (not an object with `data` property). Then it should work. Actually, you can add `expect(items).toEqual(mockResponse)`, because it's true and will provide better feedback in the case of assertion failure.

Comment: I'm quite new to webdev so there could be something extremely obvious that I have wrong :)

Here's the error message using toEqual:

`Expected Response with status: null null for URL: null to equal [ Object({ itemCharId: 1, itemName: 'milk' }), Object({ itemCharId: 2, itemName: 'eggs' }), Object({ itemCharId: 3, itemName: 'meat' }) ].`

Could that mean my getItems method isn't getting the data from the api?

Comment: Sure, now I see that. I assumed that the service is working fine in production, but it cannot work like that. You forgot to call `res.json()`. I updated the answer. You also need to have `rxjs/add/operator/map` in service file for `map` observable operator in order for this to work.